# javascript method not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a problem with javascript in Chrome. I have a form in which is a text input and a checkbox. The  textinput is defined like this:

```
<input type="text" style="display:block;", id="BroadsofTypeInput",  onblur = "CustomValidation.validate.pText(this, 550,'Required field! Maximum 550 characters!');">
```

Javascript inline function, which is called on the onblur event, validates the input. When the input is empty it adds a div element next to the input tag. The Div element displays an error message.

Next when I click on checkbox this piece of code is called:

```
   function SetVisibleContent(control) {   
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdonwtypes");
        var textfield = document.getElementById("BroadsofTypeInput");
        if (control.checked == true) {        
            ShowControl(dropdown, true);
            ShowControl(textfield, false);
            dropdown.value = "";           
        }
        else {           
            ShowControl(dropdown, false);
            ShowControl(textfield, true);           
            textfield.value = "";            
        }
        RemoveErrors();
        debugger;
    }
```

**The problem is:** When I click the checkbox to be checked the error message 
should be removed but it isn't. But thats not all, it works when the developer tools are open in Chrome and debugger line is catched.
This is where it gets crazy. When in debug mode and debugger line is catched if I click F8, the message is removed. If I click the blue button on that says "Resume script execution (F8)", it doesn't work.

Here is the link for downloading the sample code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0cu8N689t1MUVYxdkZhT2V4bzg/view?usp=sharing

```js
var CustomValidation = CustomValidation || {};
CustomValidation.validate = {
    errorEmpty: "Required field!",
    errorFormat: "Wrong format!",
    errorLength: "Value to long!",
    errorEmptyValues: "value cannot be empty!", 
    errorInterval: "Value not in interval!",
    submitButton: null,
   
    //Error message methods
    errorMsgEmpty: function (control, errorMsg) {
        $(control).focus();
        $(control).css("background", "#FF9F9F");
        if (errorMsg != "" && errorMsg != undefined)
            $(control).after('<div class="errorInputMessage">' + errorMsg + '</div>');
        else
            $(control).after('<div class="errorInputMessage">' + this.errorEmpty + '</div>');       
    },
    errorMsgEmptyValues: function (control, errorMsg) {       
        if (errorMsg != "" && errorMsg != undefined)
            $(control).after('<div class="errorInputMessage">' + errorMsg + '</div>');
        else
            $(control).after('<div class="errorInputMessage">' + this.errorEmptyValues + '</div>');
    },
    errorMsgFormat: function (control, errorMsg) {
        $(control).focus();
        $(control).css("background", "#FF9F9F");
        if (errorMsg != "" && errorMsg != undefined)
            $(control).after('<div class="errorInputMessage">' + errorMsg + '</div>');
        else
            $(control).after('<div class="errorInputMessage">' + this.errorFormat + '</div>');
    },
    errorMsgLength: function (control, errorMsg) {     
        $(control).focus();
        $(control).css("background", "#FF9F9F");
        if (errorMsg != "" && errorMsg != undefined)
            $(control).after('<div class="errorInputMessage">' + errorMsg + '</div>');
        else
            $(control).after('<div class="errorInputMessage">' + this.errorLength + '</div>');
    },   
    errorMsgInterval: function(control, errorMsg)
    {
        $(control).focus();
        $(control).css("background", "#FF9F9F");
        if (errorMsg != "" && errorMsg != undefined)
            $(control).after('<div class="errorInputMessage">' + errorMsg + '</div>');
        else
            $(control).after('<div class="errorInputMessage">' + this.errorInterval + '</div>');
    },
    //Reset input background
    resetBack: function (control) {
        $(control).css("background", "#FFFFFF");
    },
    //Check length
    checkLength: function (control, length, errorMsg) {
        if (control.value != undefined) {
            if (length != 0 && control.value.length > length) {
                this.errorMsgLength(control, errorMsg);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
    //Disable submit button
    disableButton: function(){
        var inputArray = $(".errorInputMessage");
       
        if (inputArray.length > 0)
            this.submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        else
            this.submitButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
    },
    //Validation methods 
    pInt: function (control, length, errorMsg) {
    
        var errorControl = $(control).next();
        if ($(errorControl).hasClass("errorInputMessage"))
            $(errorControl).remove();

        if (length != 0)
            if (!this.checkLength(control, length, errorMsg))
                return false;           

        if (control.value == "") {
            this.errorMsgEmpty(control, errorMsg);
        }
        //else if (isNaN(control.value) && !$(errorControl).hasClass("errorInputMessage")) {
        else if(isNaN(control.value)){
            this.errorMsgFormat(control, errorMsg);
        }
        else
            this.resetBack(control);

    },
    pFloat: function (control, length, errorMsg) {
        var errorControl = $(control).next();
        if ($(errorControl).hasClass("errorInputMessage"))
            $(errorControl).remove();

        if (length != 0)
            this.checkLength(control, length, errorMsg);

        if (control.value == "") {
            this.errorMsgEmpty(control, errorMsg);
        }
        //else if (isNaN(parseFloat(control.value)) && !$(errorControl).hasClass("errorInputMessage")) {
        else if (isNaN(control.value)) {
            this.errorMsgFormat(control, errorMsg);
        }
        else
            this.resetBack(control);

    },
    pRegex: function (control, length, regexValue, errorMsg) {
        var errorControl = $(control).next();
        if ($(errorControl).hasClass("errorInputMessage"))
            $(errorControl).remove();

        if (length != 0)
            this.checkLength(control, length, errorMsg);

        if (control.value == "") {
            this.errorMsgEmpty(control, errorMsg);
        }
        else if (regexValue.exec(control.value) == null) {
            this.errorMsgFormat(control, errorMsg);
        }
        else
            this.resetBack(control);

    },
    pText: function (control, length, errorMsg) {
     
        var errorControl = $(control).next();
        if ($(errorControl).hasClass("errorInputMessage"))
            $(errorControl).remove();

        if (length != 0) 
            this.checkLength(control, length, errorMsg);            
        
        var inputArrayError = $(".errorInputMessage");
        if (inputArrayError.length > 0)
            return false;

        if (control.value == "") {
            this.errorMsgEmpty(control, errorMsg);
        }
        else
            this.resetBack(control);

    },
    pIntervalInt:function (control, errorMsg, min, max)
    {
        var errorControl = $(control).next();
        if ($(errorControl).hasClass("errorInputMessage"))
            $(errorControl).remove();
       
        if (min > parseInt(control.value) || parseInt(control.value) > max) {        
            this.errorMsgInterval(control, errorMsg);
        }
        else
            this.resetBack(control);
    },    
    //Validate submit
    formSubmit: function () { 

        var error=0;
        var inputArray = $(".validation");
        var inputArrayError = $(".errorInputMessage");
        if (inputArrayError.length > 0)
            return false;
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {

                var errorControl = $(inputArray[i]).next();
                if ($(errorControl).hasClass("errorInputMessage"))
                    $(errorControl).remove();

                if (inputArray[i].value == "" || inputArray[i].value == null) {
                    this.errorMsgEmpty(inputArray[i], '');
                    error += 1;
                }                
            }
        }
        if (error > 0)
            return false;
        else 
            return true;

    },
    /* f - validate float,
     * i - validate int,
     * s - validate string,
     * l - validate interval
    */
    formSubmitControls: function (controls, errormsg, controlsChecked, filters, intervals) {
    
        if (this.formSubmit()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
                //Remove error message so it cannot be repeated           
                var errorControl = $(controls[i]).next();
                if ($(errorControl).hasClass("errorInputMessage"))
                    $(errorControl).remove();


                if (controlsChecked[i] != "" && controlsChecked[i] != undefined) {
                    if (controlsChecked[i][0].checked) {
                        this.filterControl(controls[i], 0, filters[i], errormsg[i], intervals[i])
                    }
                    else
                        this.resetBack(controls[i]);
                }
                else {
                    if (controls[i].value == "") {
                        //this.errorMsgEmptyValues(controls[i], errormsg[i]);
                        this.filterControl(controls[i], 0, filters[i], errormsg[i], intervals[i])
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        this.filterControl(controls[i], 0, filters[i], errormsg[i], intervals[i])
                    }
                }
            }

            var inputArray = $(".errorInputMessage");
            if (inputArray.length > 0)
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;

        return true;
    },
    filterControl: function (control, length, filters, error, interval) {
       
        var s = "";
        var min, max;        
        if (interval != "" && interval != undefined) {
            var s = interval.split(";");
            min = s[0];
            max = s[1];
        }

        if (filters.indexOf("f") != -1) {
            this.pFloat(control, length, error)
        }
        if (filters.indexOf("i") != -1) {
            this.pInt(control,length, error)
        }
        if (filters.indexOf("s") != -1) {
            this.pText(control, length, error)
        }
        if (filters.indexOf("l") != -1) {
            this.pIntervalInt(control, error, min, max)
        }
    }

   



}


 function SetVisibleContent(control) {       
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdonwtypes");
        var textfield = document.getElementById("BroadsofTypeInput");
        if (control.checked == true) {            
            ShowControl(dropdown, true);
            ShowControl(textfield, false);
            dropdown.value = "";           
        }
        else {           
            ShowControl(dropdown, false);
            ShowControl(textfield, true); 
   
            textfield.value = "";            
        }
        RemoveErrors();
  debugger;
    }

    function RemoveErrors() {
        var inputArrayError = $(".errorInputMessage");
      
        for (var i = 0; i < inputArrayError.length; i++) {   
            $(inputArrayError[i]).remove();            
        }
    }
  function ShowControl(control, show)
    {
        if (show) {
            //control.setAttribute("style", "display:block;visibility:visible;width:450px;");
            control.setAttribute("style", "display:block;width:450px;");
        }
        else {
            //control.setAttribute("style", "display:none;visibility:hidden;width:450px;");
            control.setAttribute("style", "display:none;width:450px;");
        }
    }
```

```css
.info, .success, .warning, .errorInputMessage {
 border: 1px solid;
 margin: 10px 0px;
 padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 5px center;
 }
 .info {
 color: #00529B;
 background-color: #BDE5F8;
 background-image: url('info.png');
 }
 .success {
 color: #4F8A10;
 background-color: #DFF2BF;
 background-image:url('success.png');
 }
 .warning {
 color: #9F6000;
 background-color: #FEEFB3;
 background-image: url('warning.png');
 }
 .errorInputMessage {
 color: #D8000C;
 background-color: #FFBABA;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
 <label>Text Bro!</label>
 
 <input type="text" style="display:block;", id="BroadsofTypeInput",  onblur = "CustomValidation.validate.pText(this, 550,'Required field! Maximum 550 characters!');"> 
 
<input type="text" style="display:none;", id="dropdonwtypes",  onblur = "CustomValidation.validate.pText(this, 550,'Required field! Maximum 550 characters!');">        

<input id="IsBroadsoft" name="IsBroadsoft" onchange="SetVisibleContent(this);" type="checkbox" value="true"> Is Broadsoft
 <br />
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="CustomValidation.validate.formSubmit()">
</form>
```

Comment: could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), google docs is unreachable

Comment: you have commas in tag attributes?

Comment: A hint for you to start your research: Do you call SetVisibleContent on *click* of the checkbox or on *change* ?

Comment: Click is "sometimes" being called before the actual change of the checkbox happened ... so it might be a race condition (which would also explain the debugger behavior)

Comment: I put the code into a snippet, it was put into a rar file... of all formats, who still uses rar...

Comment: `you have commas in tag attributes?` < +1, remove the commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error did removed! But then the blur event on text input trigger again, so the error show up again. 
The different behavior when you in debug mode when click F8, I guess is because you did't click on the document body, so the blur event did not triggered. And this line, and you will see:

```
pText: function (control, length, errorMsg) {
  console.log('......ptext.......');
  // other codes....................
}
```